# Add simple option to an InstallShield Express project?

Tags: task-flow

I've got a very simple, straightforward Install Shield Express project that installs our client software.

Currently, I only show a minimal set of dialogs during the installation process (Welcome, License Agreement, Destination Folder, Done).

My goal is to allow the user a way to select an option. When the option is selected, we will create 1 additional Shortcut on the desktop (that shortcut will have an additional option added to the Target section - a parameter to pass in to the .exe file).

What's the best approach to let the user to set this option/flag?

I considered enabling the "Setup Type" Dialog, and overriding the default options and creating 2 different Setups - "Normal" and "Normal with Extra Shortcut". That seems a bit sloppy to me, and a lot of work for 1 true / false option.

Answer (score 1):

Your install flow seems to be the following if I read correctly:
click to install >> welcome >> license >> destination folder >> installing... >> done!

If this is the case, and the shortcut needs to be picked before installing since it's a paramater passed to the .exe file then I'd say let users select that as a checkbox in the destination folder box. It follows to put it there logically because then they can see both locations at once.

[image]

Now all this is given the limitation that the checkbox can't be placed at the very end when installation is complete, because that is where most applications ask whether the user wants to create a shortcut or not.